# undefined form vs Indeterminate form

Tags: limits

I know $ \frac{0}{0}$ is an undefined form while $ \frac{→0}{→0}$  is an indeterminate form. Now lets say there is an expression

$$\lim_{x→3} \frac {x^3 -7x^2+15x-9}{x^4-5x^3+27x-27}$$

If I substitute 3 in it, I get $ \frac{0}{0}$. My book says it's an indeterminate form. What's stopping it from becoming an undefined form?

Also Can somebody explain me what does this expression mean $→1^{→∞}$? I mean in $f(x)$ forms, what does the expression tend to? What will the expression look like?

Comment: I think the undefined form is the same as an indeterminate form.

Comment: Tere is no such term as "undefined form", there is "undefined expression".

Answer (score 3):

In your example, as $x\to 3$, both the numerator and the denominator $\to 0$. If that isn't what you mean by $\frac{\to 0}{\to 0}$, then I don't know what else that is supposed to mean.

The value of the fraction at $x = 3$ is $\frac00$ and therefore undefined, while the limit as $x\to 3$ is of the form $\frac{\to 0}{\to 0}$, and therefore "just" indeterminate. Whether this limit actually exists and is defined, and if so what its value actually is, is a completely different question, and you would need to do some (simple, but not entirely trivial) calculus and / or algebra to figure that out.

And if you want an example of your second type of indeterminate form, then we have the very famous limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}(1+\frac1x)^x$, which is of the type $(\to 1)^{\to\infty}$. Its limit is $e\approx 2.72$. But in general, the limit of a $(\to 1)^{\to\infty}$ expression can be anything from $0$ to $\infty$ (or the limit can fail to exist). That's why we call them "indeterminate".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use inspection and factorize to get

$$\frac {x^3 -7x^2+15x-9}{x^4-5x^3+27x-27}=\frac{(x-1)(x-3)^2 }{(x-3) ^2  (x^2+x-3)}$$

Comment: i know to solve this.I am just asking when we substitute 3 why  0/0 is indeterminate form rather than undefined form

Comment: @who. Terminology issue for me (but I may be wrong). If you google for the title of your post, they are a bunch of similar questions.

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x-1}$ it means that $f(0)=0/0$ and  this means that $f(x)$ does not exist at $x=1$. Also $f(x)$ is indeterminate at $x=1$ but $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)=1$ exists.

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping it from being an **undefined** form is the part in the box:

$$\fbox{ $\lim_{x\to3}$ } \frac {x^3 -7x^2+15x-9}{x^4-5x^3+27x-27}$$

The whole point of a **limit** is it is what happens as you **approach** the given value, not what happens **at** the given value.
Just plugging in $x=3$ tells you absolutely **nothing** about the limit.

If you delete the part that says $\lim_{x\to 3}$ and replace it with
"for $x=3$," then you have an undefined form. But you can make all kinds of defined things undefined and vice versa by scratching out parts of the expressions and replacing them with something else.
You can just as well take the true statement $1 + 2 = 3,$ cross out the $3$ and write a $5$ in its place, and ask whether this shows that the original equation was false.

Now if you happen to know that a function is continuous at a certain point, and someone asks you the limit at that point, you can just plug in the value: by virtue of the definition of continuity, the plug-in evaluation at that point is also the evaluation of the limit.
But in your example the function is not continuous at $x=3.$

---

The form ${\to}{1}^{\to\infty}$ means you have something like
$\lim_{x\to a} g(x)^{h(x)}$
where $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = 1$
and $\lim_{x\to a} h(x) = \infty.$
You have already gotten an answer exhibiting a particular $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ 
where the limit as $x \to \infty$ takes this form.
But the value of the limit completely depends on exactly *which* $g(x)$ and $h(x)$
you have.